# parse boolean expression issue

Tags: java, parsing, boolean, boolean-expression

I am trying to minimize/simplify somes boolean expressions.
I would like for example :

> ((!C | C) & A & B) --> (A & B)

I saw that it exits this library to parse any boolean expression :

[JBool_expressions library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bpodgursky/jbool_expressions/1.7)

Studying this library, I choose to use it to simplify my boolean expression like below :

```
Expression<String> expr = ExprParser.parse("( ( (! C) | C) & A & B)");
Expression<String> simplified = RuleSet.simplify(expr);
System.out.println(expr);
```

I work with Eclipse but I had so many problems. I don't know why. For example, Eclipse doesen't understand what is Expression. That's what eclipse propose :

```
com.bpodgursky.jbool_expressions.Expression expr = ExprParser.parse("( ( (! C) | C) & A & B)");
```

But It says me :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/RecognitionException

**Do you have any idea why ? 
Also, to simplify myexpressions, do you know an other alternative ? An other library ? Or open source ? Or any methodology.**

As regards me, I was trying to implemted by myself the Quine McCluskey method to minmize any boolean expressions in Java.

thks

Comment: If you use a library, you had better make sure that your build path includes that library. The Eclipse documentation should help you understand how to do that. Also, make sure you don't have any other `Expression` in your import statements.

Comment: Sure, but I already import my library in my project...

Comment: `import` is not the same as setting the build path properly. The `import` command merely says "In this class file, whenever I say class X, I mean a.b.c.d.X". That's it - it doesn't check that the jar exists.

Comment: Following up on RealSkeptic's comments: If you are working in eclipse, look to the properties of your project.  Look for "Java Build Path" and on that tab, "Libraries".